# Invalid userID() when connecting Gateway to IBM watson IoT platform

Tags: websphere, ibm-cloud, mqtt, watson-iot

`this image contains mqtt parameters`

[parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ci5Zs.png)

`this image contains topic & message`

[topic & message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDjJx.png)

`this image contains the error`

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/au2oI.png)

Any insights on how to connect these problem ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the problem is on subscription action. Devices (user use-token-auth) cannot subscribe on topics such as iot-2/evt/event_id/fmt/format_string (e.g iot-2/evt/abc/fmt/json).

Devices can only publish to the event topics in the following format:

iot-2/evt/event_id/fmt/format_string

and devices can only subscribe to command topics in the following format:

iot-2/cmd/command_id/fmt/format_string

You have more details about that [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSQP8H/iot/platform/devices/mqtt.html)

Remove the subscribing action, or change topic to smth like iot-2/cmd/abc/fmt/json  and it should be ok.

Comment: I deactivate the subscription and i change the topic of publisher **iot-2 / evt / status / fmt / json**  but the problem still exists :

Invalid userID () for device auth: ClientID = 'd: hykxz8: test: test', ClientIP = 41.231.56.98, ClientPort = 5242, ConnectionId = 25550972

Comment: do you see the Invalid userID() during connection or publish action?

Comment: during publish action

Comment: does the test device connect over a gateway? the invalid userID() shows up if the user provided for the connection is empty(null).